# persistence of akka messages for routers

Tags: akka, akka-persistence

How do we handle persistence in case we are using akka routers. We would want to persist the unprocessed messages in the  mailbox and be able to process them in case of server crashes and restarts. i know classic dispatchers provide filebasedmailbox for persistence

Comment: Check out akka persistence https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/persistence.html

Comment: You want to check out [At-Least-Once Delivery](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/persistence.html#at-least-once-delivery)